# Getting quote_from_bytes() expected bytes when updating couchdb document

Tags: python, couchdb

I am trying to update an existing document and I keep getting a typeError (quote_from_bytes() expected bytes)

my code:

```
couch = couchdb.Server("<http>")
couch.resource.credentials = ("USERNAME","PASSWORD")
db = couch['mydb']

id = "183848484"
doc = db[id]

"""doing some operations on data here"""

db[id] = doc
```

My error log:

> self.db[self.docID] = doc   File
>   "/home/sunilgopikrishna/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/couchdb/client.py",
>   line 427, in **setitem**
>       resource = _doc_resource(self.resource, id)   File "/home/sunilgopikrishna/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/couchdb/client.py",
>   line 1057, in _doc_resource
>       return base(doc_id)   File "/home/sunilgopikrishna/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/couchdb/http.py",
>   line 537, in **call**
>       obj = type(self)(urljoin(self.url, *path), self.session)   File "/home/sunilgopikrishna/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/couchdb/http.py",
>   line 678, in urljoin
>       path = '/'.join([''] + [quote(s) for s in path])   File "/home/sunilgopikrishna/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/couchdb/http.py",
>   line 678, in 
>       path = '/'.join([''] + [quote(s) for s in path])   File "/home/sunilgopikrishna/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/couchdb/http.py",
>   line 630, in quote
>       return util.urlquote(string, safe)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/parse.py", line 712, in quote
>       return quote_from_bytes(string, safe)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/parse.py", line 737, in quote_from_bytes
>       raise TypeError("quote_from_bytes() expected bytes") TypeError: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes

Thanks.

Comment: There may be a typo in your coding ..check for erroneous quotes  in the `doc` variable.Provide remaining code

Comment: Hi @SmartManoj... Yes.  I believe there was an error in the code (an incorrect ' ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error in the coding (I had missed a ')